# EF generic repository Query method, how to select one column?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4

I am usign EF 4 with repository patren which have a generic query method which is coded as below:

```
 public IEnumerable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        return objectSet.Where(filter);
    }
```

I know how to query for selecting a complete object which was like below:

```
context.PeriodRepository.Query(a => a.EntityId == selectedEntityId);
```

Can you please guide me how to query not compelte object rather how to get just a property, I want to put property directly into textbox.

thanks

**Edit**

I have decided to get full object from query as:

```
MyType obj = context .Signatories1Repository.Query(a=>a.Id==signatory1Id);
```

but it shows an error:

Cannot convert from IEnumarable to type. An explicit conversion exisit. Are you missing a cast ?

Can you please advice how I can make it workign correctly ?

Comment: could you provide the implementation of `Signatories1Repository`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to retrieve just a property (or some properties), you need to call the `Select()` linq extension method for doing a transformation that will retrieve just what you want:

```
context.PeriodRepository.Query(a => a.EntityId == selectedEntityId)
       .Select(x => x.TheProperty);
```

I also suggest returning `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` in your Query method. In fact, I would avoid the query method and just make your repository implement `IQueryable<T>` so you can just use the out-of-the-box linq extension methods like `Where()` instead.

Comment: Please add some detail about how this answers the question.

Comment: Thanks@ivowiblo, can you please see my edit and guide.

Thanks once again.

Comment: @ivowiblo can you please explain "In fact, I would avoid the query method and just make your repository implement IQueryable<T> so you can just use the out-of-the-box linq extension methods like Where() instead." by an example ? Thanks